# Alternative to Galleria module?

Tags: media

I'm trying to use the http://drupal.org/project/galleria module in conjunction with its fullscreen theme, but I get the error I pasted below, I tried many fixes but not working.

**Is there another module to show a gallery similar to this one: http://galleria.io/themes/fullscreen/**

```
Could not extract width/height from image: http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/images-fullscreen/slide-1.jpg. Traced measures: width:0px, height: 0px.
```

Comment: Galleria is really great and configurable. I have not found better out-of-the-box solution for now.

Comment: I agree, I've use it en other project with no problems. But now I couldn't find a fix for this, until I the answer of Triskelion just below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happened to one of my sites, I corrected it by upgrading to the latest version of the galleria library. There also might be an issue with your css. Several hints to track the problem down can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/1308912).